# Why does the Google C++ Style Guide recommend PascalCase function names?

Tags: c++, google-style-guide

The [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Function_Names) says:

> Ordinarily, functions should start with a capital letter and have a capital letter for each new word (a.k.a. "upper camel case" or "Pascal case").

For me, Pascal case looks very unfamiliar and I'm very reluctant to adapt to that guideline. What is the style guide's reasoning behind using PascalCase?

Comment: Note: This is not about whether PascalCase is a good idea (which is an opinion), but about why the Google Style Guide recommends PascalCase.

Comment: Ask Google first please! How can we know?

Comment: I think only the author(s) of the style guide can answer this question.

Comment: using `CamelCase` for function names burns me a little because their python style guide recommends `using_underscores_for_function_names`. why wouldn't they want their Python/C++ style guides to be similar? Especially when Python/C++ are used a lot at Google for interop and integration.

Comment: Totally agree. I don't have a clue why on the Earth google use same naming  for classes and functions (and methods). It just makes developers mix up functions and classes (and methods). 
    
For example in Java there is differenent naming between methods and classes (case of first letter).

Answer (score -1):

It's a style guide, which is opinion based. If you don't like it you don't have to follow it. Function names can be all lowercase, all uppercase, or 90's chatroom style every other letter uppercase! The style guide is just a preference that produces consistent, readable code.

Comment: That actually doesn't answer _"What is the style guide's reasoning behind using PascalCase?"_.